# How to keep the v-treeview state after page refresh?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am trying to understand how to keep the state of the treeview after a page refresh.

For example, I have a treeview of folders. I click on a folder it should expand.

After that, I can click on that item inside the folder (is a link to a page, therefore the whole page is refreshed.)

The problem is the treeview closes the folders back up again and doesn't keep its previous state.

I need it to be static so even after page reload the treeview does not lose its state.

[treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxYYT.png)

This bit of code is my treeview:

```
 v-list.py-2(v-else, dense)
  v-treeview(v-model="tree", :items="treeData", activatable, :open.sync="openIds", @update:open="getOpenIds", item-key="name", open-on-click)
    template(v-slot:prepend="{item, open}")
      v-list-item(v-if="item.isFolder", link, :href='`/` + item.locale + `/` + item.path', :input-value='path === item.path')
        v-list-item-avatar(size="24", tile)
          v-icon  {{ open ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}
        v-list-item-title {{item.title}}
      v-list-item.noFolders(v-else, :href='`/` + item.locale + `/` + item.path', :key='`childpage-` + item.id', :input-value='path === item.path')
        v-list-item-avatar(size="24", tile)
          v-icon mdi-text-box
        v-list-item-title {{item.title}}
```

Also, I should mention that the data is dynamic. I am generating the tree (as an Object) using a method.

```
async buildTree(items){
  this.$store.commit(`loadingStart`, 'browse-load')
  for(let item of items){
    if(item.isFolder){
      let result = await this.$apollo.query({
        query: gql`
          query ($parent: Int, $locale: String!) {
            pages {
              tree(parent: $parent, mode: ALL, locale: $locale) {
                id
                path
                title
                isFolder
                pageId
                parent
                locale
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
        variables: {
          parent: item.id,
          locale: this.locale
        }
      })
      item.children = _.get(result, 'data.pages.tree', [])
      for(let kid of item.children){
      if(item.isFolder){
          //kid.name = ""
          kid.children = []
        }
      }
    this.buildTree(item.children)
    console.log(this.treeData )
    }
  }
   this.$store.commit(`loadingStop`, 'browse-load')
```

And that's actually the method that is supposed to save the tree state to the local storage.

```
getOpenIds(items){

   const memory = JSON.stringify(items)
    this.sessionIds = sessionStorage.setItem('items2', memory)
    this.openIds = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('items2'))
  console.log(this.openIds)
},
```

I have tried the suggestions but for some reason, the tree doesn't react to the local storage. IS there something to do with the fact that the method is async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of these 2 possibilities below (there are probably more):

### Local storage

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to keep a record of all your folders' state.

Then you can add a computed property to get the data from the local storage if it exists and apply it inside your component.

Next time you can add a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your example so someone could provide you with a detailed solution :)

How to use: when someone clicks on a folder you should have a v-on:click handler where you store in local storage the new state

```
function onClickHandler(folderName: string, isOpen: boolean) {
  localStorage.setItem(folderName, isOpen);
}
```

The next thing you should do is get the state for each folder from local storage and apply it - if it doesn't exist just return false.

```
function getFolderState(folderName: string) {
 localStorage.getItem(folderName);
}
```

Apply it on the v-list-item element and make sure to pass in the same folder name for both functions.

### Vue dynamic component

There is a built-in feature in Vue that keeps your component alive instead of dismounting when it's removed from the DOM.

You can use the [keep-alive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components) element to wrap your component. It will result in keeping all the component's state when switching between screens.

```
<keep-alive>
  <your-component />
</keep-alive>
```

Comment: I like the idea! But is there a way to do that using something that vue itself provides?

Comment: No, the Vue instance will restart on every refresh. This is why you have local storage, exactly for those use cases. 

Another common use case is for authentication data, like storing the user's token on local storage so when the user reloads the page he doesn't need to log in again. 

Hope my answer was helpful, if it does, please upvote it :) @Terar

Comment: could you give a rough example of applying it? You can see the code above, so all I need is the computed part. I think this will be helpful not just for me

Comment: Hi! I have added some more details. I checked what you suggest but it seems that it will work on static data. Have a look, please above and tell me what you think. Am I doing something wrong? The v-treeview is still closing when I try to click on a link or reload the page traditionally.

Comment: I found another solution using Vue dynamic components. Please take a look. If you find it helpful please upvote my answer :)

Comment: With this keep-alive. That means that I will have to add the v-treeview as a component (SFC)?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary.